# Why I can't setValue of specific child in database by using Model class?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

This is Messages Model Class

```
public class MessModel {
    String message;
    public MessModel() {}

    public MessModel(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

I am trying to update specific value (Last value) of message key by using setter method

This is my code

```
Query lastmess = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Messages").child(my_Id).child(sendUID);
lastmess.orderByKey().limitToLast(1).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataa) {
        for (DataSnapshot snap : dataa.getChildren()) {
            MessModel messages = snap.getValue(MessModel.class);
            String mes = messages.getMessage(); //here I can get the last message
            messages.setMessage("updated Message"); //here is the problem , why it doesn't work ?
        }
    }

    @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

I don't know why setter method doesn't work ? 
And what is the best way to setValue of all children? Or setValue of specific one?

Comment: Your code isn't calling `setValue()` anywhere that I can see.

Comment: So where can I call it ? and How can I use setter method ?
sorry but I am still beginner in Firebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
Query lastmess = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Messages").child(my_Id).child(sendUID);
lastmess.orderByKey().limitToLast(1).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataa) {
        for (DataSnapshot snap : dataa.getChildren()) {
            MessModel messages = snap.getValue(MessModel.class);
            String mes = messages.getMessage(); //here I can get the last message
            messages.setMessage("updated Message");
            snap.getRef().setValue(messages);
        }
    }

    @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

This can be done even simpler using the String class:

```
Query lastmess = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Messages").child(my_Id).child(sendUID);
lastmess.orderByKey().limitToLast(1).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataa) {
        for (DataSnapshot snap : dataa.getChildren()) {
            snap.child("message").getRef().setValue(updated Message);
        }
    }

    @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

Comment: thanks for help , the second solution is working well .. but the first doesn't work .. I can't use setValue in  'lastmess.setValue(messages);'

Comment: I voted it up but, for sorry, I can't accept it as the right answer until I find out the answer of my main question which is : How to setValue by using Model class ? I mean by using setter method !

Comment: What is the error that you get when using my first solution? The code should work in the same way as the second.

Comment: I can't use setValue here  `lastmess.setValue(messages);` it appears in red color and it show cannot resolve method 'setValue'

Comment: I understand. Please see my updated answer. Does it work now?